# html img-tag: can't find Image in same folder

Tags: html, image, angular, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to make a Slideshow for my WebApp with Angular 2. The problem is, when I try to display an image I get a 404-Error.
[Error-Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDtnF.png)

[image]

The picture is in the same folder as my html-file.

```
<img *ngIf="i == activeIndex" src="try1.png" style="width:100%; height: 500px">
```

PS: The *ngIf isn't the problem it perfectly works with an internet source.

Comment: check weather the URL generated in browser for that image pointing to correct folder or not

Answer (score 1):

Simply keep your images in assets folder and use path as

```
src="/assets/try1.png"
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

try to add it to your `.angular-cli.json` file under `assets` section:

```
"assets": [
  "assets",
  "favicon.ico",
  "try1.png"
]
```

and make sure your image file is located in `src/` directory